# React/Webpack/Django - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'XXX' of undefined

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, mapping, react-props

I am trying to create a React component called 'Proposals' that will render a tabular list of information received from the Django backend.

I am using the [Reactable-Search component](https://github.com/dbjohnson/reactable-search) to form the table, but I've kept getting an error when I try to map the this.props.proposals values such as id, and proj_name to the table cells - **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined**

Really not sure why because when I map this.props.proposals directly in the render return of a typical html table tags it is working i.e. rendering the backend data ok. and I've also used the Reactable-Search component with the mapping in other cases and it's worked fine.

Log output of this.props.proposals shows the correct array of objects also...:
[image: screenshot]

Really appreciate if someone can nudge me in the right direction, thanks!

The Proposals component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import SearchTable from "reactable-search";
import { proposals } from "../actions";

class Proposals extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProposals();
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    var rows = this.props.proposals.map(p => ({
      selected: this.state.selectedRow === p.id,
      onClick: () => {
        this.setState({ selectedRow: p.id });
      },
      cells: {
        "#": p.id,
        "Project Name": p.proj_name
      }
    }));

    return (
      <SearchTable
        showExportCSVBtn={true}
        searchPrompt="Type to search"
        rows={rows}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    proposals: state.proposals
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchProposals: () => {
      dispatch(proposals.fetchProposals());
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Proposals);
```

The proposals reducer:

```js
const initialState = [];

export default function proposals(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_PROPOSALS":
      return [...action.proposals];

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The proposals action

```js
export const fetchProposals = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    let headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
    return fetch("/api/proposals/", { headers })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(proposals => {
        return dispatch({
          type: "FETCH_PROPOSALS",
          proposals
        });
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you post the `initialState` of your `proposals` reducer? Try logging the `this.props.proposals` in the `render` method and see if it actually prints the expected output.

Comment: Hi Eugene - when I log this.props.proposals it does output the expected array of objects... I've also added the reducer and action files. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are requesting the proposals asynchronously but the `SearchTable` component doesn't seem to work with empty initial proposals object. Try passing in an empty array as its `rows` prop and you'll get the exact same error message about undefined object.

To fix this you need to show a loading indicator instead of the `SearchTable` while the proposals are being fetched. Your reducer should look something like this, except you should also handle failure case:

```
const initialState = { isLoading: false, error: null, proposals: [] };

export default function proposals(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_PROPOSALS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true
      };
    case "FETCH_PROPOSALS_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        proposals: action.proposals
      };
    case "FETCH_PROPOSALS_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        error: action.error,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The component should then render an activity indicator or loading status or anything other than `SearchTable` when isLoading is active:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import SearchTable from "reactable-search";
import { proposals } from "../actions";

class Proposals extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProposals();
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { proposals, error, isLoading } = this.props;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    if (error) {
      return <div>{error.message}</div>;
    }
    if (proposals.length === 0) {
      return <div>No proposals</div>;
    }

    var rows = proposals.map(p => ({
      selected: this.state.selectedRow === p.id,
      onClick: () => {
        this.setState({ selectedRow: p.id });
      },
      cells: {
        "#": p.id,
        "Project Name": p.proj_name
      }
    }));

    return (
      <SearchTable
        showExportCSVBtn={true}
        searchPrompt="Type to search"
        rows={rows}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    proposals: state.proposals.proposals,
    isLoading: state.proposals.isLoading,
    error: state.proposals.error,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchProposals: () => {
      dispatch(proposals.fetchProposals());
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Proposals);
```

And the thunk action:

```
export const fetchProposals = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: "FETCH_PROPOSALS"});
    let headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
    return fetch("/api/proposals/", { headers })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(proposals => {
        dispatch({
          type: "FETCH_PROPOSALS_SUCCESS",
          proposals
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({
          type: "FETCH_PROPOSALS_FAILURE",
          error,
        });
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: Wow - thanks so much for the clear and prompt response and explanation. The solution is right! I was stuck all day on this, cheers